# Get Maximum Value across rows and columns of a python Matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, max

Consider the question:

```
The grid is:
[ [3, 0, 8, 4], 
  [2, 4, 5, 7],
  [9, 2, 6, 3],
  [0, 3, 1, 0] ]

The max viewed from top (i.e. max across columns) is: [9, 4, 8, 7]
The max viewed from left (i.e. max across rows) is: [8, 7, 9, 3]
```

I know how to define a grid in Python:

```
maximums = [[0 for x in range(len(grid[0]))] for x in range(len(grid))]
```

Getting maximum across rows looks easy:

```
max_top = [max(x) for x in grid]
```

But how to get maximum across columns?

Further, I need to find a way to do so in linear space O(M+N) where MxN is the size of the Matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip`:

```
result = [max(i) for i in zip(*grid)]
```

In Python, `*` is not a pointer, rather, it is used for unpacking a structure passed to an object's parameter or specifying that the object can receive a variable number of items. For instance:

```
def f(*args):
  print(args)

f(434, 424, "val", 233, "another val")
```

Output:

```
(434, 424, 'val', 233, 'another val')
```

Or, given an iterable, each item can be inserted at its corresponding function parameter:

```
def f(*args):
  print(args)

f(*["val", "val3", 23, 23])
>>>('val', 'val3', 23, 23)
```

`zip` "transposes" a listing of data i.e each row becomes a column, and vice versa.

Comment: please explain a bit more: the pointer notation, the zip function...thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([ [3, 0, 8, 4],
  [2, 4, 5, 7],
  [9, 2, 6, 3],
  [0, 3, 1, 0] ])

print(x.max(axis=0))
```

Output:

```
[9 4 8 7]
```

You said that you need to do this in O(m+n) space (not using numpy), so here's a solution that doesn't recreate the matrix:

```
max = x[0]
for i in x:
    for j, k in enumerate(i):
        if k > max[j]:
            max[j] = k

print(max)
```

Output:

```
[9, 4, 8, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured a shortcut too:

transpose the matrix and then just take maximum over rows:

```
grid_transposed = [[grid[j][i] for j in range(len(grid[0]))] for i in range(len(grid))]

max_left = [max(x) for x in grid]
```

But then again this takes `O(M*N)` space I have to alter the matrix.

I don't want to use numpy as external libraries are not allowed in any assignments.

Comment: @Ajax's answer is much better than this.  If you can't use numpy then use that

Comment: @chrisz yes, however I need to find a way to do so in linear space O(M+N), not sure the internal functions zip and *grid allow this to be in linear time.

Comment: These are details you should really include in your question.

Comment: I just added a solution that does inplace lookup for the maximum values, without recreating the matrix

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.max.html)'s array max:

```
array.max(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like these works both ways and is quite easy to read:

```
# 1.
    maxLR, maxTB = [], []
    maxlr, maxtb = 0, 0
    
    # max across rows
    for i, x in enumerate(grid):
        maxlr = 0
        for j, y in enumerate(grid[0]):
            maxlr = max(maxlr, grid[i][j])
        maxLR.append(maxlr)
    
    # max across columns
    for j, y in enumerate(grid[0]):
        maxtb = 0
        for i, x in enumerate(grid):
            maxtb = max(maxtb, grid[i][j])
        maxTB.append(maxtb)

# 2.

row_maxes = [max(row) for row in grid]
col_maxes = [max(col) for col in zip(*grid)]
```